# how to fix Gecko 29.0 error (sec_error_unknown_issuer) on a website?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, geckofx

I am using Gecko 29.0 in winforms. I have written some basic code as following:

```
using Gecko;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
namespace GeckoTutorial1
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
GeckoWebBrowser browser;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var app_dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(Path.Combine(app_dir, "xulrunner"));

    browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();

    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.browser.Name = "browser";

    this.Controls.Add(browser);

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    browser.Navigate("http://www.Someexample.com");
}
}
}
```

and it gives me the following error:

*"cms.nust.edu.pk uses an invalid security certificate The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided (sec_error_unknown_issuer)"*

I have tried to make it https from http. but it didnot work. I have searched everywhere, but couldn't find any solution or even a hint.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

So the solution is here for someone who is beginner like me facing issue of invalid certificate

```
private void geckoWebBrowser1_ValidityOverride(object sender, Gecko.Events.CertOverrideEventArgs e)
    {
        e.OverrideResult = Gecko.CertOverride.Mismatch | Gecko.CertOverride.Time | Gecko.CertOverride.Untrusted;
        e.Temporary = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Put this inside your constructor:

```
  Gecko.CertOverrideService.GetService().ValidityOverride += geckoWebBrowser1_ValidityOverride;
```

Comment: This code not for 33 or 45 version. There is no ValidityOverride event for 29 version